# Spring Boot RequestMapping with non-standard produces value returning 406 error when returning JAXB annotated object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, spring-boot

I'm creating a Spring Boot app to replace a legacy api application, so all the routes/headers/etc are already set in stone. In that legacy app we used custom Accept headers to include both the version and the content type. So our Accept header is like:

catalog.v1.xml  or catalog.v2.json etc.

Here is my request mapping for the method that is handling the request. I'm trying to handle the v1.xml one now. Spring is finding the correct method and the whole method is executed and it returns my JAXB annotated object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catalog", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/catalog.v1.xml")
```

How do I make sure Spring finds this matching handler method based on my Accept header, but knows that the output should be XML and marshall my JAXB object accordingly?

Comment: Not tested, but you'll probably have to provide your own implementation of [ContentNegociationManagerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.html) that adds a custom ContentNegotiationManager to the default list of managers.

Comment: So I've gotten that far myself. I did create a Configuration class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and I overrode configureContentNegotiation method. I added my custom mimetype to it: 

configurer.mediaType("application/catalog.v1.xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

But it's still not working. I'm debugging into the Spring code and it does add this mimetype and it seems to get further than it had before I added this configuration class. But somewhere down the line it checks to see if it's compatible with application/xml and it's coming back false. So I'm still missing something somewhere

Comment: The first argument of the method you called is a file extension. So that can't possibly work. You need to extend this bean and make it return XML based on the accept header, not based on a file extension.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't realize that was for file extensions. So I figured it out by extending the message converters. I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide Spring MVC with an `HttpMessageConverter` for your custom media type. To do so, I'd take advantage of Spring Boot automatically adding any `HttpMessageConverter` beans to Spring MVC's default configuration by configuring a bean that knows how to convert `application/catalog.v1.xml`:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter catalogXmlConverter() {
    Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
    xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "catalog.v1.xml")));
    return xmlConverter;
}
```

Comment: This is much simpler than my approach of trying to modify the message converters that Spring already had registered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So once I realized I was changing the wrong configuration, and from deep debugging into Spring code, I realized I needed to replace or modify the message converter behavior. Here is my solution below. They don't make it super easy. If anyone has a simpler way of doing this, please let me know. This works.

```
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)     
{
    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
        if (converter.getClass() == MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class){
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)converter;
            MediaType jsonType = new MediaType("application", "catalog.v2.json");
            MediaType jsonpType = new MediaType("application", "catalog.v2.jsonp");

            List<MediaType> mediatTypes = new ArrayList<>(jacksonConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
            mediatTypes.add(jsonpType);
            mediatTypes.add(jsonType);
            jacksonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediatTypes);
        }
        else if (converter.getClass() == Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.class){
            Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = (Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter) converter;
            MediaType xmlType = new MediaType("application", "catalog.v1.xml");

            // Since the SupportMediaTypes list is unmodifiable, we have to create a new one based on it
            // and replace it completely
            List<MediaType> mediatTypes = new ArrayList<>(xmlConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
            mediatTypes.add(xmlType);
            xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediatTypes);
        }
    }
}
```